# MVC (Model View Controller); Please explain me this method

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Well I am trying to learn the java MVC pattern, but I can't understand the following method:

```
protected void setModelProperty(String propertyName, Object newValue) {

        for (AbstractModel model: registeredModels) {
            try {

                Method method = model.getClass().
                    getMethod("set"+propertyName, new Class[] {
                                                      newValue.getClass()
                                                  }
                             );
                method.invoke(model, newValue);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //  Handle exception
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont' understand the:

```
Method method = model.getClass().
                    getMethod("set"+propertyName, new Class[] {
                                                      newValue.getClass()
                                                  }
                             );
```

So in getMethod we are retrieving the (setSomething) method name according to the property, then the following "thing" is the property value as newValue which is expressed in this fancy expression that I don't understand at all.

`new Class[]`  <--- So it's an array of classes???
next `{ newValue.getClass() }`  <---- OK, getting the class name in brackets by calling the method, but what about the semicolon? There must be some special structure that I don't understand, it looks like a class, but that must be something different if there's no semicolon... People explain me what this is please...

Comment: It is not linked with MVC but with introspection / reflextion. You can dynamically see and invoke methods of any object with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an abstract way of coding, and to be honest I'd discourage this way of working if it's possible to do it otherwise (e.g. by using templates), especially at beginners level. Anyway, I'll try to explain.

All classes in Java are also objects of the class Class. And all methods are objects of the class Method. You can manipulate these objects like any other objects, by calling their methods and using them as arguments for other methods and so on. That way, you can perfectly instantiate a class by only knowing its name as a String. Same for methods: you can call a method by simply knowing its name as a String.

Now let's look at your code. Have a quick look at [this entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29) in the Java API for a brief explanation of this part `getMethod("set"+propertyName, new Class[] {newValue.getClass()});`.

Say you want to call the method `setParameter(int parameterValue) {...}`. In that case, we call your method with `propertyName` set to `"Parameter"` and `newValue` set to a certain integer `123`. Now `"set"+propertyName` results in `setParameter`, which is the name of our method. `newValue.getClass()` gives `Integer`, since that's what `123` is.

The `getMethod` requires an array of Classes though, because there may exist a number of methods with the same name, but a different number and types of arguments (e.g. there is a chance the method `setParameter(double parameterValue) {...}` exists as well). So we put that `newValue.getClass()` in an array with only one item, by writing `new Class[] {newValue.getClass()}`.

And there you have it: you retrieve a `Method` object by calling

`Method method = model.getClass(). getMethod("set"+propertyName, new Class[] {newValue.getClass()});`

and then you call that method using `method.invoke(model, newValue);`, which is simply a dynamic way of calling `setParameter(123)`.

Answer (score 2):

With the:

```
new Class[] { newValue.getClass() }
```

you are specifying an array of classes inline, and passing it to the argument of getMethod.

It's probably a bit more confusing due to having "Class" in the mix, but it's just as valid as something like:

```
Integer[] bla = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4};
```

getMethod receives as arguments the name of the method you are looking for in a Class, and an Array of Classes that specify the parameters of said Method. Example:

```
getMethod("setValues", new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class}
```

will look for a method like:

```
public Something setValues(String p1, Integer p2)
```

It would not match, even if it exists in the same class, something like:

```
public Something setValues(String p1)
```

or any other variation.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about the array syntax, this is just how you define an array in Java:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
String[] stringArray = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
Class classArray = new Class[] {Integer.class, String.class, Double.class};
```

The expression `new Class[] {newValue.getClass()}` is thus an array of `Class` instances, containing one element: the result of `newValue.getClass()`, which is thus the class of `newValue`.

Note that I don't know where you got this code from, but I wouldn't call it good code:

- it uses reflection, which is, most of the time, a bad idea;
- it doesn't respect JavaBean conventions, and doesn't use `java.beans` API to get access to the setter method.
- it doesn't support inheritance, which means that you can only call `setFoo(Object o)` with an object of type Object (and not String, Integer, or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you call the method like

```
setModelProperty("Key", "value");
```

then the code in the loop will search all registered models for methods with the signature

```
<any modifiers> <any returntype> setKey(String value);
```

and invoke that method on the next line.

It will take the property value to construct a setter method name and the values class to get a `Class` instance. The `getMethod` method takes an array of classes just because we want to be able to find methods with more then one argument.